# ActionScript3 : Argument Error on constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, argument-error

I have a real problem on an ActionScript homework. I have to program a solitaire, and I'm now stuck on a bug that I don't understand.
When I launch my game object, it instanciates a CardDeck object, and fill its array with Card objects. But since my last edit, a "ArgumentError: Error #1063" is thrown every 2 seconds, and i just don't get why. I've looked and tried the few topics related to this Error, but I didn't manage to make it work ...

Here are my classes :

- Card.as

  ```
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.utils.Timer;

  public class Card extends MovieClip
  {
  public static const COLOR_RED:int = 1;
  public static const COLOR_BLACK:int = 2;

  public static const SYMBOL_HEART:int = 1;
  public static const SYMBOL_DIAMOND:int = 2;
  public static const SYMBOL_SPADE:int = 3;
  public static const SYMBOL_CLUB:int = 4;

  public var game:Game;

  private var t:Timer; // For click/double click fix
  private var currentTarget:Card;

  public var container:CardStack;
  public var color:int;
  public var symbol:int;
  public var value:int;
  public var isVisible:Boolean = false;

  public function Card(type:int, value:int, g:Game) 
  {
      game = g;

      if (type == SYMBOL_HEART || type == SYMBOL_DIAMOND)
          this.color = COLOR_RED;
      else
          this.color = COLOR_BLACK;

      this.symbol = type;
      this.value = value;

      this.doubleClickEnabled = true;
      this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);
      this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, doubleClick);
  }

  private function doubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
  {
      t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onCardClick);
      if (t.running)
          t.stop();
      onCardDoubleClick(e);
  }

  private function Click(e:MouseEvent):void 
  {
      currentTarget = (Card)(e.currentTarget);
      t = new Timer(100,1);
      t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onCardClick);
      t.start();
  }


  public function isSameColor(otherCard:Card):Boolean
  {
      if (this.color == otherCard.color)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }

  public function setVisible(flipped:Boolean):void 
  {
      if (flipped == true)
      {
          isVisible = true;
          gotoAndStop(value);
      }
      else {
          isVisible = false;
          gotoAndStop(14);
      }
      game.pStage.addChild(this);
  }

  public function setInvisible():void
  {
      removeListeners();
      game.pStage.removeChild(this);
  }

  public function removeListeners():void 
  {
      this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);
      this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, doubleClick);
  }

  private function onCardClick(e:TimerEvent):void 
  {
      var card:Card = currentTarget;

      if (this.isVisible == true) {
          if (game.flagSelecting == false) {
              if (!(card.container == game.deck && game.deck.isHeadCard(card) == false))
                  game.select.addToSelect(card);
          }else{
              if (card.container == game.deck)
                  game.deck.lastPickedCard--;

              game.mvOutCard(game.select.tSelect, card.container);
          }
      }else {
          if (((card.container.deckSize()) - 1) == (game.selCard(card, card.container)))
              card.setVisible(true);
      }
  }

  private function onCardDoubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
  {
      var card:Card = (Card)(e.currentTarget);

      // Acestack
      if (game.aceStacks.canMoveTo(card) == true)
      {
          game.moveToAce(card);
      }

      //K sur place libre
      if (card.value == 13) {
          var freeStack:CardStack = (game.river.hasFreeStack());

          if (freeStack != null){
              game.select.addToSelect(card);
              game.moveKing(game.select.tSelect, freeStack);
          }       
      }

      game.select.reinitSelection();
          }

  }
  ```
- CardDeck.as

  ```
  import Math;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class CardDeck extends CardStack
  {
          // THIS IS ABOUT CARDDECK
          public var lastPickedCard:int = 0;
  public var isEmptyNow:Boolean = false;

  // THIS IS ABOUT HANDSTACK
  public var handStack:Array = new Array();

  public static const X_FIRST_HANDCARD:int = 120;
  public static const X_CARD_PADDING:int = 18;
  public static const Y_HANDSTACK:int = 62;

  public function CardDeck(g:Game) 
  {
      trace("GAME" + g);
      var a:Array = new Array();
      var nGame:Game = g;
      super(a,g); 
      trace("CONSTRUCTEUR2");
      var i:int = 1;

      while (i <= 52)
      {
          if (i < 14)
              this.deck.push(new HeartCard(i,g));
          else if (i >= 14 && i < 27)
              this.deck.push(new DiamondCard(i - 13, g));
          else if (i >= 27 && i < 40)
              this.deck.push(new SpadeCard(i - 26, g));
          else if (i >= 40)
              this.deck.push(new ClubCard(i - 39, g));

          i++;
      }

      trace("CONSTRUCTEUR3");
      var nDeck:Array;
      nDeck = new Array();
      var idx:int;

      while(this.deck.length > 0){
          var r:int = Math.random()*(this.deck.length);
          idx = (Math.floor(r));
          //deck[idx].container = game.deck;
          nDeck.push(deck.splice(idx, 1)[0]);
      }

      trace("CONSTRUCTEUR4");
      this.deck = nDeck;

      this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onDeckClick);

      this.game.pStage.addChild(this);
      this.x = 46;
      this.y = 62;
      trace("CONSTRUCTEUR5");
  }

  private function onDeckClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
  {
      trace("LISTENER");
      if (isEmptyNow == false)
          fillHand();
      else
          setFilled();
  }

  public function setEmpty():void 
  {
      this.alpha = .2;
      this.isEmptyNow = true;         
  }

  public function setFilled():void
  {
      this.alpha = 1;
      this.isEmptyNow = false;
      this.reinitHS();
  }


  // HANDSTACK
  public function showHand():void
  {
      var i:int = 0;

      while (i < (this.handStack.length)) {
          trace("SHOW HAND");
          handStack[i].setVisible(true);
          handStack[i].y = Y_HANDSTACK;
          handStack[i].x = X_FIRST_HANDCARD + (i * X_CARD_PADDING);
          i++;
      }

      this.setDepth();
  }

  public function fillHand():void
  {
      trace("FILL");
      if(lastPickedCard < (deck.length)-3)
          this.handStack = this.deck.slice(deck.lastPickedCard, 3);
      else {
          this.handStack = this.deck.slice(game.deck.lastPickedCard);
          this.setEmpty();
      }

      showHand();
  }


  public function reinitHS():void {

      var i:int = 0;

      while (i < (this.handStack.length)) {
          handStack[i].setInvisible();
          i++;
      }

      this.handStack = new Array();
  }

  public function isHeadCard(c:Card):Boolean
  {
      if (handStack.indexOf(c) == handStack.length -1)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
  }
  ```
- CardStack.as

  ```
      import flash.display.MovieClip;

      public class CardStack extends MovieClip
      {
              public var deck:Array;

              public var game:Game;

              public function CardStack(newDeck:Array, g:Game)
              {
          game = g;
          this.deck = newDeck;
      }

  public function isEmpty():Boolean {

      if (this.deck.lenght == 0)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }

  public function setDepth():void 
  {
              var i:int = 0;
              while (i < (this.deck.length))
              {
                      if (i == 0)
                              this.deck[i].parent.setChildIndex(this.deck[i], 1);
                      else
                              this.deck[i].parent.setChildIndex(this.deck[i], 1 + i);
          i++;
      }

  }

  public function deckSize():int {return (this.deck.length);} 

  }
  ```

I call this here :

```
    public function Game(pS:Stage)
    {
        pStage = pS;

        select = new Selection(this);

        trace("flag");
        deck = new CardDeck(this);
        trace("flag2");
        aceStacks = new AceRiver(this);

        river = new River(deck.deck, this);
    }
```

And I get this exception :

```
 ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on CardDeck(). Expected 1, got 0
```

Any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: try running in debug mode to find out exactly what line is causing this issue

Comment: I did, but it doesn't show me the line ...

Comment: `CardDeck` extends `CardStack`.  What is `CardStack` ? a Class ? Is it a library symbol with linkage ? Also, is `CardDeck` a library symbol with linkage ? And if so, are either used as stage timeline instances ? You might get this type of error if you have an instance of a symbol on the stage timeline that has linkage set. Reason being that if it's a stage timeline instance, there is no way for a parameter to be passed to the constructor - but it is expecting that based on the class definition.

Comment: CardStack is a generic "abstract" class, which only contains an Array and a reference of the current game. I updated my post with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark; assuming that the only line that calls CardDeck() is:

```
deck = new CardDeck(this);
```

then I would ask, are you using more than one swf file in your project and loading one in at runtime? If so, try rebuilding all of your swfs that reference the CardDeck class.

Comment: Yes, i checked it, a CardDeck is built only once.
I use only one swf, and rebuilt it, without reslut ...